# Handling null values in Map keys

Tags: cassandra

I am using cassandra 3.10 and in order to use a Group by function on non primary partitions I am referring: http://www.batey.info/cassandra-aggregates-min-max-avg-group.html, which is using map keys to do the same. When I execute `select group_and_total(name,count) from school;` and I get the error `ServerError: java.lang.NullPointerException: Map keys cannot be null`. 
The problem is that name column has some null values in it and is there any way by modifying the function and getting the desired result instead of removing the rows that have null values in it.

The schema of the table is

```
Table school{
name text,
count int,
roll_no text,
...
primary key(roll_no)
}
```

The functions that I am using for Group by are:

```
CREATE FUNCTION state_group_and_total( state map<text, int>, type text, amount int )
CALLED ON NULL INPUT
RETURNS map<text, int>
LANGUAGE java AS '
Integer count = (Integer) state.get(type);  if (count == null) count = amount; else count = count + amount; state.put(type, count); return state; ' ;


CREATE OR REPLACE AGGREGATE group_and_total(text, int) 
SFUNC state_group_and_total 
STYPE map<text, int> 
INITCOND {};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Schema that you mentioned

```
CREATE TABLE temp.school (
    roll_no text PRIMARY KEY,
    count int,
    name text
)
```

Sample inputs into the table

```
 roll_no | count | name
---------+-------+------
       6 |     1 |    b
       7 |     1 | null
       4 |     1 |    b
       3 |     1 |    a
       5 |     1 |    b
       2 |     1 |    a
       1 |     1 |    a

(7 rows)
```

Note: There is one null value in the name column.

Modified Function definition

```
CREATE FUNCTION temp.state_group_and_total(state map<text, int>, type text, amount int)
    RETURNS NULL ON NULL INPUT
    RETURNS map<text, int>
    LANGUAGE java
    AS $$Integer count = (Integer) state.get(type);if (count == null) count = amount;else count = count + amount;state.put(type, count); return state;$$;
```

Note: removed `CALLED ON NULL INPUT` and added `RETURNS NULL ON NULL INPUT`

Aggregate definition:

```
CREATE AGGREGATE temp.group_and_total(text, int)
    SFUNC state_group_and_total
    STYPE map<text, int>
    INITCOND {};
```

Query output:

```
cassandra@cqlsh:temp> select group_and_total(name,count) from school;

 temp.group_and_total(name, count)
-----------------------------------
                  {'a': 3, 'b': 3}

(1 rows)
```